# sql check to see any data changes to an existing account

Tags: sql

I have `table A` with all existing `accounts`.  I need `Table A` to look to `Table B` to see anytime the `Code` field is populated or updated or some data is added.  The requirement is to see any changes to the Code field on `Table B`.

The requirement needs to see anytime the `Code` is added to any existing account. What the account looked like previous day vs. what the account looks like today to show only the changes to the Code field from `Table B`.

The requirement also needs to see all accounts even if the the Code field didn't have anything prior to the change.

I've tried NOT EXISTS function, but I'm able to get what I need.

I've tried CTE's with row_number() - but not able to make it work.

```
 FROM       T1 A
        JOIN        T1 B ON A.ACCTNBR = B.ACCTNBR AND A.RN = B.RN2 - 1
        WHERE       A.CODE <> B.CODE
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered a trigger on the code field?

Comment: After data in table B is inserted, are changes reflected by modifying the existing records B.Code field or is a new B record inserted?

Comment: The data is loaded nightly through a batch process, so I just need to be able to query and build a report to capture any changes that are loaded (if any)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: 2008 R2........